# Opening a router 6 link thats refreshed

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In the edit page, I have this button to go back to the profile page:

```
<Button handleClick={()=>{navigate(-1)}} >Finished</Button>
OR
<Button handleClick={()=>{navigate('/userprofile/view')}} >Finished</Button>
```

The page is opening but it's showing the previous (data) version and not the updated data until I refresh the browser. Is there a way to open this link in router 6 refreshed? i.e. to reload the loader method?

**Update**

Here is my browser router:

```
const router=createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:'/',
    element: <MainHeader  />,
    errorElement:<Error/>, 
    id:'root',
    loader:tokenLoader,
    action:actionLogin(ctx),
    children:[
        {index:true, element:<Home  />, loader:()=>loaderHome(numPerPage) },
        {path:'userprofile', id:'userprofileview', loader:loaderUserProfileView,
        children:[
          {index:true, path:'view', element:<UserProfileView/>, 
            loader:checkAuthLoader, action:actionUserAccountDelete },
          {path:'edit', element:<UserProfileEdit/> }
        ] 
      },
      {path:'logout', loader:actionLogout(ctx), action:actionLogout(ctx)}
    ]
  }
])
```

**Update**

I got it working. Posting my answer in case others meet up the same problem. I set `shouldRevalidate` in the parent route to true and now the button `<Button handleClick={()=>{navigate('/userprofile/view')}}`  is working, when click the user profile page is retrieving the up-to-date data

```
const router=createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path:'/',
    element: <MainHeader  />,
    errorElement:<Error/>, 
    id:'root',
    loader:tokenLoader,
    action:actionLogin(ctx),
    children:[
        {index:true, element:<Home  />, loader:()=>loaderHome(numPerPage) },
        {path:'userprofile', id:'userprofileview', loader:loaderUserProfileView, shouldRevalidate:()=>true,
        children:[
          {index:true, path:'view', element:<UserProfileView/>, 
            loader:checkAuthLoader, action:actionUserAccountDelete },
          {path:'edit', element:<UserProfileEdit/> }
        ] 
      },
      {path:'logout', loader:actionLogout(ctx), action:actionLogout(ctx)}
    ]
  }
])
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to include the code that needs to be "refreshed"? See [mcve]. Can you also clarify what the overall UI/UX flow is to be? This looks like the user has stepped through some page(s) and is clicking a button to "complete" a task/flow and needs to navigate back to a starting point. You/we may need to take a step or two back to see the overall picture to really understand what the issue may be.

Comment: @DrewReese I'm trying something new. I already got edit pages working properly with an edit button posting to an action method. What I'm doing here however is real-time updating: as the user is typing without the need for a Form posting. I included a useEffect and setTimeout every 1000 ms (for optimization) updating the Database as the user is typing in page. I've checked the Database and everyting is updating real-time.

Comment: My `finish` button is simply linking back to the `view profile page` to display the updated data but even though the Database has been updated, the loader isn't refreshing and it's showing the previous version of the data. I got something working in the interim, `<Button handleClick={()=>{navigate('/')}} >Finished</Button>` I navigated to home and then click the `view profile button`  in my web page and I'm seeing the updated data. However navigating directly to `view profile page` is not showing the updated data

Answer (score -1):

can you check this document?

**https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/routing/**

you should use component proper.

```
import {
   Link
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

<Button component={Link} to="/">
     With prop forwarding
</Button>
```

Comment: I tried this and while it's linking to the router, it's still not updating the data